# Isotope pre-filtering triggered by link in another page

Tags: hyperlink, filter, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope to display an image grid of design projects thumbnails, sorted by product category (lifestyle, car accessories, electronics, etc.) on my home page. I am using `<li>` items to filter the thumbnails.

I would like those `<li>` items to act as hyperlinks to my home page from every other page of my website and pre-filter the home page isotope grid when clicked.

I've looked up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562283/isotope-filter-to-link-from-another-page) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604652/jquery-isotope-filter-from-different-page-wordpress) but none of them worked for me. Could anyone be of some help?

Here is what I have so far (adapted from the first link above) :

JS:

```
var $container = $('.grid');

$container.isotope({
// options
isInitLayout: true,
});

    // filter items on button click
    $('#filter').on( 'click', 'li', function() {
      var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
    });

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('#filter').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'li', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
});

var filterFromQuerystring = getParameterByName('filter');
$('#filter li a[data-filter=".' + filterFromQuerystring  + '"]').click();

    });

});
```

Filter nav as seen on the home page:

```
<ul id="filter">
  <li class="is-checked" data-filter="*">All</li>
  <li data-filter=".lifestyle">Lifestyle</li>
  <li data-filter=".car">Car accessories</li>
  <li data-filter=".lighting">Lighting</li>
  <li data-filter=".digital">Digital</li>
  <li data-filter=".bnc">Beauty & Care</li>
  <li data-filter=".equipment">Equipment</li>
</ul>
```

Filter nav as seen on any page but the home page:

```
<ul id="filter">
  <li><a href="index.html" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html?filter=lifestyle" data-filter=".lifestyle">Lifestyle</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html?filter=car" data-filter=".car">Car accessories</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html?filter=lighting" data-filter=".lighting">Lighting</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html?filter=digital" data-filter=".digital">Digital</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html?filter=bnc" data-filter=".bnc">Beauty & Care</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html?filter=equipment" data-filter=".equipment">Equipment</a></li>
</ul>
```

Image grid as seen on the home page:

```
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="lifestyle"><a href="gallery1.html"><img src="images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li class="lifestyle"><a href="gallery2"><img src="images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li class="lighting"><a href="gallery3.html"><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a></li>
[...]
</ul>
```

I hope everything makes sense, looking forward to hearing from you!

Thank you!